# Player allowed to play for main pot after folding during side pot action?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, side-pots

There are three players: A, B and

A has $25, B has $50, and C has $100

A goes all-in
B and C call
Later in the hand, C makes B fold

Now, as B folded, will B be allowed to play for the main pot?

Comment: Your hand is dead if it is mucked.

Comment: Life would be so easy if you could compete for side pots only. Well, or hell. Knowing everyone else can get in for cheap too.

Answer (score 11):

No, B folded. They are no longer in the hand. Cards are tabled, main pot of 75$ goes to A or C, depending on who has the best cards. If a side pot exists it goes to C.